# Default Value Error Python, ipywidgets : When linking model to widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I am linking **model** with **ipywidgets**  as below:

```
import ipywidgets as w
import traitlets as t
from enum import Enum 

class A(t.HasTraits):
   trait_A = t.Enum(..., defaultValue=...)

   def __init__(self):
     pass

dropdown_widg = w.Dropdown(options(['0', ...], ['1',...])
```

creation of link between widget and model is defined as below:

```
a = A()
w.link((a, 'trait_A'), (dropdown_widg, value))
```

As soon as i run the **Jupyter** notebook, I am getting below error

> No default value found for trait_A trait of ...

P.S: I have debugged this issue and doing below will solve the issue

```
def __init__(self):
  trait_A = EnumType.ZERO
```

as above will assign default value to traitlet.

***My question is that*** : Do i need to do it for every trait that i define under class? Say I have 20 traits under class and in `__init__`, do i need to assign default values to all 20 traits.

:) *I am newbie in Python* :)

Comment: Have you tried removing `__init__` altogether or calling `super().__init__()` method in it? My hunch is that traitlets will do the initialization with default values for you but you need to let them do so; by writing custom empty `__init__` you are disabling the default init of parent class; this is the direction I would explore.

Comment: yeah. I tried removing `__init__` and also tried `super().__init__()` now. Getting same error